# How to make an effect strip stay on screen in the video editor?

Tags: rendering, animation, edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video

I have two visual tracks on screen at the same time, the main track that lasts 300 frames and an effect track that shows an animation in the top right corner. The effect track showing the animation is 160 frames. When the animation ends I would like the last frame of the animation to remain in that spot until the main track ends, but because the effect track is only 160 frames long the visual disappears after that. How do I make the last frame of the effect strip just stay there until the main track is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I didn't understand your question, but that should be easy. I suppose you have a timeline as in Figure 1. To make sure that the last frame remains until the other strip ends, you have to grab the handle at the right and extend the strip; see figure 2. Because there aren't enough frames for that duration, the last frame is extended; you can see it by the slightly different color in the strip.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could just make an image of your last frame and drag and drop this at the end of your shorter track. then just size it til the end of the other track. then add adjustment to adapt your wished size.